# How can i solve this Error Subsequent property declarations must have the same type and Duplicate identifier. Angular 9

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

*** I really dont know and dont understand why this is happening, im new using Angular ***

- Below i will let my full code and the complete error

***Error***`Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'post1' must be of type 'Posts', but here has type 'any'` and `Duplicate identifier 'post1'`

***Post class***

```js
export class Posts{
    Key:string;
    Email:string;
    Password:string;
}
```

***AppComponent class where i use the `post class`***

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyecto-nro2';

  post1 = new Posts();
//Said the error above in every post1.
  post1.Key = 'NONE';
  post1.Email = 'NONE';
  post1.Password = '2';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nayakam said you should set the properties in the constructor of your Posts object

```js
export class Posts{
    key: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(key: string, email: string, password: string) {
        this.key = key;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it can become annoying if some parameters are optionals, for me the best syntax is to send an object to initialize your models and export an interface so that your AppComponent knows what the Posts constructor needs as input

```js
export interface IPosts {
    key: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export class Posts{
    key: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(inputData: IPosts) {
        this.key = inputData.key;
        this.email = inputData.email;
        this.password = inputData.password;
    }
}

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'proyecto-nro2';
    post1: Posts = new Posts({
       key: 'NONE',
       email: 'NONE',
       password: '2'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Properties can't initialised directly on a class in ES6. Initialise the post object inside the constructor and set the properties.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyecto-nro2';

  post1: Posts;

 constructor(){
  this.post1 = new Posts();
  this.post1.Key = 'NONE';
  this.post1.Email = 'NONE';
  this.post1.Password = '2';

 }
}
```

**Other Option:**

```
class Posts {
    Key: string;
    Email: string;
    Password: string;

    constructor(key: string, email: string, password: string) {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
    }
}

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyecto-nro2';
  post1: Posts = new Posts('NONE', 'NONE', '2');
}
```